# How to see source of linked image in PowerPoint?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, links

I have a PowerPoint presentation made in Office 2016, where I am linking to some images in a folder. Thus, when the pictures change (e.g. due to being updated with new data), the images in the presentation are also updated. This is all good. After a while, though, it becomes hard to keep track of the images and their names and locations.

**My question:** How do I find the source URL of an image in the presentation? So for example, if the image is linked to c:\some-picture.jpg, I'd like to know how I can see this path and filename for the image in PowerPoint?

I know that I can see a list of all links to files in the File menu by clicking "Edit Links to Files" - however, this shows all links and don't show the connection between which images belong to which files, and this is a problem with e.g. 50+ images in a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

I have a commercial PowerPoint add-in that does a variety of useful things with links. The free demo version includes a link report feature that lists the slide number, shape name and full file name (including path) to each linked picture or other linked file it finds.  More info and download are here:

http://www.pptools.com/fixlinks/

Or if you want to try your hand at a little VBA coding, this will give you the info you're after:

```
Sub ListLinkedPictures()

    Dim sList As String
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
                sList = sList & vbCrLf & oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            End If
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox sList

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the embedded pictures, with "File" > "Edit Links to Files" and then replace them with local copies.

https://wsuccess.typepad.com/webinarblog/2017/04/can-you-solve-the-powerpoint-external-pictures-problem.html

For newer office versions "File" > Information > "Edit Links to Files" (On the right under related documents)

Answer (score 0):

To find the linked excel file to a chart in PowerPoint 2016, click on the chart in your slide, click on the funnel icon which appears next to the figure, click edit links,  it goes to the set of linked files, and highlights the linked file to the figure.